# std::future_error при пересоздании std::promise

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Нужно синхронизировать два потока, пока один не запросит данные, другой их не отдает и ждет запроса на данные.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <future>
int main() {

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> pause_queue(100, 2800); //если дельта в двух местах превысит 1с

    std::atomic_size_t count(100);

    using Ready = std::promise<void>;
    Ready ready;
    using Data = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;
    Data val(10, 0);

    using Request = std::promise<Data&>;
    Request rqst;
    std::thread t1([&](){
        while(--count) {

            auto ftr = ready.get_future();
            auto s = ftr.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            if (std::future_status::ready != s) {
                std::cout << "t1 timeot!" << std::endl;
                ready = Ready();
                continue;
            }
            std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
            ready = Ready();
            rqst.set_value(val);
            const auto pause = pause_queue(gen);
            std::cout << "t1 pause: " << pause << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(pause));
        }

    });

    std::thread t2([&](){
        for(;count != 0;) {
            const auto pause = pause_queue(gen);
            std::cout << "t2 pause: " << pause << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(pause));
            ready.set_value();
            auto ftr = rqst.get_future();
            if(ftr.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) != std::future_status::ready) {
                std::cout <<"t2 timeout" << std::endl;
                rqst = Request();
                continue;
            }
            auto& rslt = ftr.get();
            std::cout<< "t2 recive " << rslt.size() << std::endl;
            rqst = Request();

        }
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Падает на пересоздании Ready-промиса в деструкторе - не устраивает, что промис имеет результат.

Comment: Мне кажется, что ничего не мешает например вызову `ready.set_value();` два раза подряд для неизменного объекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя два раза устанавливать значение, так что при тайм-ауте терпи, ничего не делай. Попробуй такой подход:

```
// g++ --std=c++11 -pthread prom.cpp
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <future>
int main() {

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> pause_queue(100, 2800); //если дельта в двух местах превысит 1с

    std::atomic_size_t count(50);

    using Ready = std::promise<void>;
    Ready ready;
    using Data = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;
    Data val(10, 0);

    using Request = std::promise<Data&>;
    Request rqst;
    std::thread t1([&](){
        while(--count) {
            std::cout<<"t1:count="<<count<<std::endl;
            auto ftr = ready.get_future();
Again:

            auto s = ftr.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));            
            if (std::future_status::ready != s) {
                std::cout << "t1 timeot!" << std::endl;
                goto Again;            }
            std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
            ready = Ready();
            rqst.set_value(val);
            const auto pause = pause_queue(gen);
            std::cout << "t1 pause: " << pause << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(pause));
        }

    });

    std::thread t2([&](){
        for(;count != 0;) {
            std::cout<<"t2:count="<<count<<std::endl;
            const auto pause = pause_queue(gen);
            std::cout << "t2 pause: " << pause << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(pause));
            ready.set_value();
            auto ftr = rqst.get_future();
Again:        
            if(ftr.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) != std::future_status::ready) {
                std::cout <<"t2 timeout" << std::endl;
                if(count==0)break;
                goto Again;            }
            auto& rslt = ftr.get();
            std::cout<< "t2 recive " << rslt.size() << std::endl;
            rqst = Request();
        }
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```